# NSDate subtract one month

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I want two NSInteger year, month to go one month back. e.g. now is **2011-01** how can I get **2010-12**. adding is one thing, but I want to subtract.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
[calendar release];
NSString * pdf_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file_%d_%02d.pdf", year, month];
```

greets endo

**EDIT: My solution**

```
    NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
 NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
 NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
 NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];

 BOOL substractOneMonth = YES;
 if (substractOneMonth) {
  if (month==1) {
   year--;
   month = 12;
  }else {
   month--;
  }
 }
 [calendar release];

 NSString * pdf_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file_%d_%02d.pdf", year, month];
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This sample code is from iPhone's Date and Time Programming Guide.

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", today);
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setMonth:-1]; // note that I'm setting it to -1
NSDate *endOfWorldWar3 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
NSLog(@"%@", endOfWorldWar3);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry when im going with your solution im getting: 4021-12-12 08:32:40 +0000

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Here's my output: 2011-01-06 03:49:28 +0000 and 
2010-12-06 03:49:28 +0000. I'd love to hear an explanation why we're seeing different results..

Comment: i see, sry i had old vars in use. shame on me!

Comment: Good to know! I, for one, was pretty surprised that the `NSDate` didn't handle more of this. Though I understand why they separated out this functionality, it seems more to Apple's pattern to make `NSDate` handle more of this type of stuff.

Comment: @donkim: Can you link to that programming guide, even if it's just an Amazon link?  I searched and couldn't find anything by that name.  Thanks.

Comment: @endo: I made a very minor edit to the answer, which should allow you to change your vote.

Comment: Thanks for the example....was very helpful! For those of you wanting to change the output format you can use NSDateFormatter and modify to your liking.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest creating an extension for this purpose:

```
extension Date {

    func adding(months: Int) -> Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

        var components = DateComponents()
        components.calendar = calendar
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        components.month = months

        return calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: self)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let now = Date()
let sixMonthsBefore = now.adding(months: -6)
let threeMonthsAfter = now.adding(months: 3)
```

Answer (score 7):

While the accepted answer works, it uses code depreciated in iOS 8.0. Another way to do the same thing without using deprecated code is as follows:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setMonth:-1];
date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];

month -= month - 1;

if (month < 1) {
 year -= 1;
 month = 12;
}

[calendar release];
NSString * pdf_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file_%d_%02d.pdf", year, month];
```

Comment: Np! Edit: Fixed month in edge case