# NSDate 1 year ago

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

Consider a start date and an end date:

```
NSDate *startDate, *endDate;
```

For example, startDate could be Dec 10, 2010 and endDate could be Jan 4, 2011.

Consider the span of days from Dec 10, 2010 to Jan 4, 2011.

How could I determine the date range over that same span of days but exactly 1 year ago. And I'd like it to take into consideration leap years. So I'm unable to simply subtract 365 days from each date.

I'd like to end up with:

```
NSDate *oneYearAgoStartDate, *oneYearAgoEndDate.
```

So maybe in this case, oneYearAgoStartDate would be Dec 10, 2009 and oneYearAgoEndDate would be Jan 4, 2010 (note that I haven't confirmed this).

How could I initialize these two variables to achieve what I need.

Comment: Check if [NSDate subtract period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611390/nsdate-substract-one-month/4611496#4611496) answers your question, with minimal adaptation (replacing `setMonth` by `setYear`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say you want to take a look at [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html), specifically the method [`-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:). In your instance, the [`NSDataComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents) instance would have a `year` of -1.