# Subtract minutes from NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I want to subtract some minutes 15 min 10 min etc., And i am having date object with time now i want to subtract minutes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out my answer to this question: [NSDate substract one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611390/nsdate-substract-one-month/4611496#4611496)

Here's a sample, modified for your question:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", today);
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setMinute:-10]; // note that I'm setting it to -1
NSDate *endOfWorldWar3 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
NSLog(@"%@", endOfWorldWar3);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: NSGregorianCalendar is deprecated from iOS 8 onwards. Maybe we can update this answer.

Answer (score 75):

Use following:

```
// gives new date object with time 15 minutes earlier
NSDate *newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15];
```

Comment: @Ishu Make sure you are not passing an unsigned integer.I did that mistake.

Comment: This is simpler but there are some edge cases it misses (leap seconds, for example). This applies any time you see something assuming there are 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, or any other shortcut. Using the other `NSCalendar` answers to this question leverages an existing set of functionality that has already handled all of the edge cases for you.

Answer (score 11):

Since iOS 8 there is the more convenient `dateByAddingUnit`:

```
//subtract 15 minutes
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute, value: -15, toDate: originalDate, options: nil)
```

Answer (score 9):

The current Swift answer is outdated as of Swift 2.x.  Here's an updated version:

```
let originalDate = NSDate() // "Jun 8, 2016, 12:05 AM"
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: -15, toDate: originalDate, options: []) // "Jun 7, 2016, 11:50 PM"
```

The `NSCalendarUnit` `OptionSetType` value has changed to `.Minute` and you can no longer pass in `nil` for `options`.  Instead, use an empty array.

Update for Swift 3 using the new `Date` and `Calendar` classes:

```
let originalDate = Date() // "Jun 13, 2016, 1:23 PM"
let calendar = Calendar.current
let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate, options: []) // "Jun 13, 2016, 1:18 PM"
```

Update the code above for Swift 4:

```
let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate) // "Jun 13, 2016, 1:18 PM"
```